# Chartjs and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, charts

I try draw a image

#### Case 1:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results track by $index">
  <div id="chartSD{{$index}}"
    class="col-12 column-with-left-padding column-with-right-padding"
    style="height: 500px">
    <div class="divider-40"></div>
    <canvas id="chartSDG0"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

In js:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("chartSDG0");
console.log(obj)   // =>      <canvas id="chartSDG0">
var BALANCE_SHEET_chart = new Chart(obj, {
```

This works!

---

#### Case 2:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results track by $index">
  <div id="chartSD{{$index}}"
    class="col-12 column-with-left-padding column-with-right-padding"
    style="height: 500px">
    <div class="divider-40"></div>
    <canvas id="chartSDG{{$index}}" ng-attr-id="{{'chartSDG' + $index}}"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

In js:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("chartSDG0");
console.log(obj)   // =>      null
var BALANCE_SHEET_chart = new Chart(obj , { // => error in this line because obj  is null
```

Doesn't work! In second case, I get `null` in obj, and this error:

```
Error: t is null
acquireContext@http://localhost:8080/xxx/assets   /chart.bundle.min.js?compile=false:10:173954
construct@
http://localhost:8080/xxx/assets/chart.bundle.min.js?compile=false:10:105079
t@
http://localhost:8080/xxx/assets/chart.bundle.min.js?compile=false:10:129391
```

Comment: I updated my post, i tried your comment and not work

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results track by $index">
      <div id="{{'chartSD0_'+ $index}}"
        class="col-12 column-with-left-padding column-with-right-padding"
        style="height: 500px">
        <div class="divider-40"></div>
        <canvas id="{{'chartSDG_'+ $index}}"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You might be getting an error if you have a repetitive key in your json. so you can try track by $index and update and handle the Id of elements accordingly.

Post the error you are getting in the console.

Comment: put the debugger in the binding code. it seems something is breaking in json.

Comment: var obj = document.getElementById("chartSDG0");
console.log(obj)   =>      null
var BALANCE_SHEET_chart = new Chart(obj , { => error in this line because obj  is null

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `ng-attr-id` for dynamic ids

Here is an example with your code:

```html
<div ng-repeat="result in results track by $index">
  <div ng-attr-id="{{'chartSD' + $index}}" class="col-12 column-with-left-padding column-with-right-padding" style="height: 500px">
    <div class="divider-40"></div>
    <canvas ng-attr-id="{{'chartSDG' + $index}}"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will render it as `id="chartSD0"`, etc. Then your `document.getElementById` will be able to select it correctly.

Comment: I modified my post, now bothe cases have ng-repeat, i try your solution but not work

Comment: @sirdaiz in your second case you still have `id` on your `<div>` tag, try replacing it with `ng-attr-id`

Comment: @sirdaiz (I didn't notice at first, but) also remove any `id` if you are using `ng-attr-id`